# Blender to Unreal. Parented mesh .fbx export breaking

Tags: animation, mesh, export, import, parent

I have parented my objects in order to animate slight movement (ie. arm lifting up). Therefore there was no need to create an actually animation rigg for this.  Parenting just for rotation worked. I exported out as .FBX. However upon importing the .FBX my robots finger and/or shoulder piece imports in at a different translate point (Flyaway mesh pieces). I've checked the pivots and seems to be fine for the rest of the Robot mesh. I realized this error (broken finger mesh) was floating in the Viewport and .avi. So question is, how do I export a parented mesh from Blender? *I DID select all object/ mesh in Viewport in Blender and without using the outliner and this still gave the same results. I assume theres a hierarchy I would need to select but I don't know.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]